# Where to store description data for markers to avoid outofmemory errors?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xml-parsing, out-of-memory, android-maps-extensions

I have 1700 markers with strings holding a description for each marker on the map. I am getting the out of memory error since I am holding so many strings for each markers "click for more info" next screen activity. How can I better hold this data and share it on marker click and not have this memory issue? I am pulling my data from an XML based file.

Here is my error log after crash:

```
10-07 13:42:55.383: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1063K, 57% free 9611K/21959K, external 2506K/2804K, paused 77ms
10-07 13:42:57.109: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1580K, 56% free 9821K/21959K, external 2551K/2804K, paused 114ms
10-07 13:42:57.320: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 427K, 55% free 10016K/21959K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 97ms
10-07 13:42:57.656: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 168K, 54% free 10142K/21959K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 166ms
10-07 13:42:57.804: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 118K, 54% free 10218K/21959K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 85ms
10-07 13:42:57.922: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 47K, 54% free 10320K/21959K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 71ms
10-07 13:42:58.031: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 119K, 54% free 10297K/21959K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 70ms
10-07 13:42:58.148: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 51K, 53% free 10342K/21959K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 69ms
10-07 13:42:58.148: I/dalvikvm-heap(4431): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.855MB for 33642-byte allocation
10-07 13:42:58.226: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 10375K/22023K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 77ms
10-07 13:42:58.328: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 83K, 54% free 10343K/22023K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 73ms
10-07 13:42:58.336: I/dalvikvm-heap(4431): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.863MB for 40183-byte allocation
10-07 13:42:58.406: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 10383K/22087K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 72ms
10-07 13:42:58.476: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 42K, 54% free 10379K/22087K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 71ms
10-07 13:42:58.609: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 62K, 53% free 10381K/22087K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 78ms
10-07 13:42:58.750: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44K, 53% free 10421K/22087K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 79ms
10-07 13:42:58.758: I/dalvikvm-heap(4431): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.005MB for 111024-byte allocation
10-07 13:42:58.844: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 10529K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 75ms
10-07 13:42:58.961: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 53% free 10528K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 111ms
10-07 13:42:58.992: E/dalvikvm-heap(4431): 32-byte external allocation too large for this process.
10-07 13:42:58.992: W/OSMemory(4431): External allocation of 32 bytes was rejected
10-07 13:42:59.070: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 10528K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 68ms
10-07 13:42:59.187: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 32K, 53% free 10535K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 69ms
10-07 13:42:59.187: I/dalvikvm-heap(4431): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 40194-byte allocation
10-07 13:42:59.250: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 10534K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 67ms
10-07 13:42:59.258: E/dalvikvm-heap(4431): Out of memory on a 40194-byte allocation.
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431): "its_ter" prio=5 tid=13 RUNNABLE
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058b398 self=0xfcfe0
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431):   | sysTid=4443 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=1036568
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~122)
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at maps.m.y.a((null):-1)
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at maps.k.d.a((null):-1)
10-07 13:42:59.258: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at maps.k.g.handleMessage((null):-1)
10-07 13:42:59.265: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 13:42:59.281: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-07 13:42:59.281: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at maps.k.d.c((null):-1)
10-07 13:42:59.281: I/dalvikvm(4431):   at maps.ao.b.run((null):-1)
10-07 13:42:59.289: W/System.err(4431): OutOfMemory
10-07 13:42:59.429: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 53% free 10567K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 128ms
10-07 13:42:59.539: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 435K, 54% free 10235K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 75ms
10-07 13:42:59.539: I/dalvikvm-heap(4431): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 119952-byte allocation
10-07 13:42:59.633: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 111K, 55% free 10123K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 97ms
10-07 13:42:59.734: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 54% free 10241K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 85ms
10-07 13:42:59.765: E/dalvikvm-heap(4431): 32-byte external allocation too large for this process.
10-07 13:42:59.765: W/OSMemory(4431): External allocation of 32 bytes was rejected
10-07 13:42:59.844: D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 54% free 10241K/22215K, external 2365K/2804K, paused 69ms
10-07 13:42:59.890: W/dalvikvm(4431): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-07 13:42:59.914: W/dalvikvm(4431): threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-07 13:42:59.922: I/Process(4431): Sending signal. PID: 4431 SIG: 9
```

I am posting them on the map like so:

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.snotel_marker);
                int nsize = visibleMarkers.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
                    MapMarkers marks = new MapMarkers();
                    String title = visibleMarkers.valueAt(i).getTitle();
                    String desc = visibleMarkers.valueAt(i).getDesc();
                    Float latitude = visibleMarkers.valueAt(i).getLat();
                    Float longitude = visibleMarkers.valueAt(i).getLon();

                    m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .title(title).icon(icon));

                    marks.setTitle(title);
                    marks.setDesc(desc);

                    m.setData(marks);
```

On Info Window Click the next activity is populated like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(extras.getString("name"));
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, extras.getString("description"),
                    "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

The app runs fine on my GNex, but on my old Droid, it populates the map, then after clicking on 3 or 4 markers and moving the map around I get the out of memory error. Any other output I can share to try and figure this out?

EDIT heap dump from MAT - String is the issue according to this:

```
 Problem Suspect 1




9,566 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 2,299,848 (34.18%) bytes. 

Keywords
java.lang.String


Details »

  Problem Suspect 2




3,381 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 960,088 (14.27%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:
•class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0x4018c9d0 - 126,632 (1.88%) bytes. 


Keywords
java.lang.Class

Details »
```

Comment: Generate a heap dump and use MAT to determine where your memory is going.

Comment: This video should help you see how to interpret MAT: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk